# OAuth/BearerTokens in ChainLink

Tags: chainlink, authentication

How to add an authentication header for ChainLink API requests?

For example, [this](https://blog.chain.link/connect-smart-contract-to-twitter-api/) guide on connecting ChainLink to Twitter API to post a tweet doesn't implement anything of the sort, so how would it post the tweet?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use an [external adapter](https://docs.chain.link/docs/external-adapters).

The node side has the OAuth information. So you don't add the information into the smart contract itself.

You can check out the [Twitter External Adapter](https://github.com/tweether-protocol/twitter-cl-ea) and see that all the password information is actually stored on the node, and the jobId on the node is associated with the external adapter.

Comment: Does this mean that I would have to either run my own node or pass on my OAuth credentials to some node operator (and get the specific jobId) to run my application? Thanks

Comment: Yes. At the moment you’d have to do one of those two. You could also put your passwords on chain with some encryption, but that’s not recommended.